# I want to post data to http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet using angularjs&cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, json, cordova, postdata

I want to post data to the above link(in spite of using a `webservice`) using `cordova` and `angularjs`. I have used alerts in between to know which functions are working properly. sign Up Function is not working, it is entering the function but not entering the request method to post data.
Is there any error in `request.success(function(data)`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport"content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <title>Post Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="HelloApp" ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
        <form role="form"  action="#">
            <div>
                Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"><br>
                Country: <input type="text" ng-model="country"><br>
                Twitter: <input type="text" ng-model="twitter"><br>
                <button ng-click="signUp()">Save</button><br>
                <span>{{responseMessage}}</span>           
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script>
        alert('Before controller');
        var helloApp = angular.module("HelloApp", []);
        helloApp.controller("HelloCtrl", [ '$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) 
        {
            alert('Entered Controller');
            $scope.name = "Calvin Hobbes";
            $scope.country = "US";
            $scope.twitter = "as@gmail.com";

            $scope.signUp = function () {
                /*  $scope.Message = "Button clicked."*/
                alert("Button CLicked");;
                var request = $http({
                    method: "post",
                    dataType:'json',
                    url: "http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet",
                    crossDomain : true,
                    data: {
                        'name': $scope.name,
                        'country': $scope.country,
                        'twitter': $scope.twitter
                    },
                        headers: { 'Accept':' text/plain','Content-Type': 'textjson' }
                });
                /* Successful HTTP post request or not */
                request.success(function(data) {
                    alert("success function");
                    if(data == "1"){
                        $scope.responseMessage = "Successfull";
                    }
                    if(data == "2"){
                        $scope.responseMessage = "failed";
                    } else if(data == "0") {
                        $scope.responseMessage = "Error";
                    }  
                });
            }
        }]);
   </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

How can i post the data to the `webservice`(http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet)

Comment: Change your Content-type to application/json and also you are using new version of angularjs. So .success is removed. use .then instead

Comment: Only success handler is attached so you will not find out if any error is thrown during web-request. Check Developer tools Network tab to see if any error during web-request call. Also attach error handler in the request object to get logs.

Comment: Just curiously asking how do you print a pdf page dynamically ?

Comment: @Vivz I tried .then and changed the content-type but still success function is not working

Comment: Did you change success to then? Are you getting any errors? And all your checks inside with data should be replaced by data.data like if(data.data == "1"). For more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @vivz Thanks. Now Its working fine but post data happens only on clicking twice.

Comment: Change your form tag <form role="form"  ng-submit="signUp()"> and your button like this <button type="submit">Save</button><br> @AmruthaJRaj

Comment: @Vivz But that had no change. Actually i removed this line  <span>{{responseMessage}}</span> and everything was fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your controller the following way. Since you are using the new version of angularjs, change `.success` to `.then`. And also when you are using form, it is better to use `ng-submit`

**JS**:

```
$scope.signUp = function () {
                /*  $scope.Message = "Button clicked."*/
                alert("Button CLicked");;
                var request = $http({
                    method: "post",
                    dataType:'json',
                    url: "http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet",
                    crossDomain : true,
                    data: {
                        'name': $scope.name,
                        'country': $scope.country,
                        'twitter': $scope.twitter
                    },
                        headers: { 'Accept':' text/plain','Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                });
                /* Successful HTTP post request or not */
                request.then(function(data) {
                    alert("success function");
                    if(data.data == "1"){
                        $scope.responseMessage = "Successfull";
                    }
                    if(data.data == "2"){
                        $scope.responseMessage = "failed";
                    } else if(data.data == "0") {
                        $scope.responseMessage = "Error";
                    }  
                });
            }
```

**HTML**:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="signUp()">
            <div>
                Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"><br>
                Country: <input type="text" ng-model="country"><br>
                Twitter: <input type="text" ng-model="twitter"><br>
                <button type="submit">Save</button><br>
                <span>{{responseMessage}}</span>           
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Please accept if it helped you by checking the tick mark. :) For more info https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work